# Can't install Adobe Flash Plugin in 10.10

Tags: 10.10, flash, software-center

I installed the Adobe Flash plugin from the software center. Installation took a long and never finished.

After a reboot the package is marked as installed but Firefox still says its missing this plugin. I tried uninstalling it from the software center but it just says 'removing" for ever.

What can I do?

**UPDATE**

```
$ sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I  guess it's because it's still being "removed" (although the software center window is closed).

**UPDATE 2**

After a reboot:

```
$ sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up flashplugin-installer (10.1.85.3ubuntu1) ...
Downloading...
--2010-10-17 11:18:31--  http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_10.1.85.3.orig.tar.gz
Resolving archive.canonical.com... 91.189.88.33
Connecting to archive.canonical.com|91.189.88.33|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

--2010-10-17 11:21:41--  (try: 2)  http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_10.1.85.3.orig.tar.gz
Connecting to archive.canonical.com|91.189.88.33|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

--2010-10-17 11:22:04--  (try: 3)  http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_10.1.85.3.orig.tar.gz
Connecting to archive.canonical.com|91.189.88.33|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

--2010-10-17 11:22:52--  (try: 4)  http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_10.1.85.3.orig.tar.gz
Connecting to archive.canonical.com|91.189.88.33|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

And I guess it will keep on...

**UPDATE 4**

Seems like this is related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/661979?comments=all

**UPDATE 5**
I tried removing it first then install again using `apt-get`:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  flashplugin-installer
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 188kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
(Reading database ... 120250 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing flashplugin-installer ...

$ sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  xulrunner-1.9 firefox-3.0 konqueror-nsplugins msttcorefonts
  ttf-bitstream-vera ttf-dejavu ttf-xfree86-nonfree xfs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  flashplugin-installer
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/20.0kB of archives.
After this operation, 188kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously deselected package flashplugin-installer.
(Reading database ... 120229 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking flashplugin-installer (from .../flashplugin-installer_10.1.85.3ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Setting up flashplugin-installer (10.1.85.3ubuntu1) ...
Downloading...
--2010-10-17 11:26:48--  http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_10.1.85.3.orig.tar.gz
Resolving archive.canonical.com... 91.189.88.33
Connecting to archive.canonical.com|91.189.88.33|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

--2010-10-17 11:27:34--  (try: 2)  http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_10.1.85.3.orig.tar.gz
Connecting to archive.canonical.com|91.189.88.33|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

Comment: Could you open a terminal (Applications->Accessories->Terminal) and tell us what happens if you enter `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer` (you will need to enter your password)

Comment: @fluteflute: see update to the op.

Comment: Thank you. Did you run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` as running the command after reboot suggested?

Comment: The first issue was because you had the Software Center or Synaptic opened when you tried to install via terminal. The second problem should be fixed with the suggested command from the error report.

Comment: @lovinglinux: I only tried terminal after Software Center has failed. See update 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that flashplugin-installer actually downloads the flash tar.gz from Canonical's partner repository (even if is not enabled). It seems that repository is down frequently lately. Is not the first time I see this problem. Get the deb file from Adobe directly http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/